# How to change TabWidget's background color from XML in Android

Tags: android-tabhost, android, android-xml, android-tabactivity

I have come across this problem. I have a tab widget on top of the view, with four tabs in it. I have been asked to change the background color of the whole tab view area. Not for any tab, but the whole area of that tab view.

I also been asked for not changing any source code for some branding reason. So I could only do it through xml file. I searched around but seems all solution is by using java code. So I wonder if there is a way that I could change the widget background color (just color, not images) by using only resources files?

Here is my layout file for the tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tabbackgroundcolor" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

You could see that I added "android:background="@color/tabbackgroundcolor"" in the TabWidget part, however it not work..

Thank you!

Comment: you have to create a custom background from your tabs, you can't do that for whole tabwidget as far as i know.